# Write a function called login(). Needs password, 3 attempts

Tags: python

Write a function called login(). You need to meet all the following requirements.

In your function, create a variable called password and assign it a string value. Prompt user to enter password, and compare the user input with the password , and if they are equal (use == operator to compare strings), print out a hint message “You are logged in!”; else if print out a message “Incorrect password, try again”.

Use loops to allow user to enter password three times. If they do not get the right password with three tries, print out message "You failed too many times. Your account is locked".

I'm unsure if I am doing this correctly, I'm pretty sure it's simple, kinda stuck here, please help!

```
def login(password):
    print('Enter correct password')
count=0
while count<3:
    password=input('Enter password: ')
    if password=='Passcode123':
    print("You are logged in!")
    count=5
elif password !=1:
    print("Incorrect")
    count+=1
else:
    print("You tried too many times, locked")
    count >=3
```

Comment: `password` cannot be equal to `1` because it's a string. It's not clear to me what that check is supposed to do. Please also fix the indentation.

Comment: Apart from indentation fix. Can you explain the line `count=5` ? Why not just break the loop if password is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python username and password with 3 attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202331/python-username-and-password-with-3-attempts)

Comment: If you've solved your problem, either write an answer to your question or delete it, but please don't remove the content of your post to say you've solved your problem.