# How do i repeat the code multiple times? in python

Tags: python

How do I make the code reapte such that users can guess the answer to the random number only three times, how do I make it stop at a point? Thanks.
This is a random number guessing game, I'm a total beginner to python and can't find anything that helps me on the web (or it may be that I'm just dumb)

```
import random
print('what difficulty do you want? Type Easy or Hard accordingly')
difficulty = input('')

if difficulty == 'Hard':
    print('your going to have a tough time')
    hardrandomnum = random.randint(1,100)
    def main():
        print('try to guess the number')
        playerguess = float (input(""))
        if playerguess > hardrandomnum: 
            print ("guess a lower number")
        if playerguess < hardrandomnum:
            print("guess a higher number")
        if playerguess == hardrandomnum:
            print("correct") 
        

        restart = 4
        if restart >4:
            main()

        if restart == 4:
            exit()

main()
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a [`while` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python username and password with 3 attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202331/python-username-and-password-with-3-attempts)

Answer (score 6):

Loops and breaks.

For example if you want to run the code three times wrap it in a for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
   [here goes your code]
```

or you could make a while loop and break:

```
while(True):
    [here goes your code]
    if condition is met:
        break
```

Comment: thank you for replying, while i knew about the for loop before I did not know how to properly integrate it into my code, Thank you for that

Answer (score 2):

you could use a for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    #your code
```

the number in range() indicates how many times you visit the code inside
there are also while loops but for your usecase a for loop should do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use a looping structure as [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540982/10237506) mentions.

##### Example with `while` loop

```py
def repeat_user_input(num_tries=3):
    tries = 0
    result = []

    while tries < num_tries:
        tries += 1
        result.append(float(input()))

    return result


print(repeat_user_input())
```

##### Example with a list comprehension and `range`

```py
def repeat_user_input(num_tries=3):
    return [float(input()) for _ in range(num_tries)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like the below?

```
import random
import sys
guess_counter = 0
random_number = 0
easy_hard = input('Chose your difficulty lever by typing "easy" or "hard" ')
if easy_hard.lower() == 'easy':
    print('Your in luck! You are about to have fun')
    random_number = random.randint(1,10)
elif easy_hard.lower() == 'hard':
    print('Woow this game is not going to be easy')
    random_number = random.randint(1,100)
else:
    print('You need to type either easy or hard and nothing else')
    sys.exit()
while guess_counter < 4:
    user_number = int(input('Guess: ')) 
    if user_number < random_number:
        print('Try higher number')
        guess_counter += 1
    elif user_number > random_number:
        print('Trye lower number')
        guess_counter += 1
    else:
        print('Congrats! You Won')
        break
else:
    print('Ooops! Looks like you luck run out.')
```

Answer (score 0):

## This is a guess the number game.

```
import random

guesses_taken = 0
number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('Well, ' + Name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

while guesses_taken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.') 
    guess = int(input())

    guesses_taken = guesses_taken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guesses_taken = str(guesses_taken)
    print('Good job, ' + Name + '! You guessed my number in ' + guesses_taken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```